# Which Box2D-like physics engine parameters need pixel conversion?

Tags: physics, box2d, physics-engine, farseer-physics-engine

The official guide does not have any useful details on the matter:

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Position is an obvious one. What about velocity? Density? Anything else?

Update: the context is wrapping/interfacing a physics engine to make it more usable. E.g. units of measure in the game editor should be consistent.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "pixel conversion" and provide an example for what you want to achieve?  Also, your question seems vague and does not state a clear problem you are having.

Comment: everything is relative, box2d works better (more efficient and accurate) with lower numbers. if you have a box that is 30x30 and apply a force or 10,0 to it, it would have the same effect as having a box 30/ratiox30/ratio and applying a force of 10/ratiox0/ratio.

Comment: @d3dave Box2d recommends using SI units and converting to pixels when something needs to be drawn. When creating a new entity, specifying its position in pixels is natural, but it raises the questions of what kind of units should be used for other parameters? E.g. |entity.Position = "{x:10px, y:10px}"| vs |entity.BodyDensity = "53kg/m^3"|.

Comment: @Den: No,  when creating a physical entity it's position needs to be specified in physical units, not pixels. Only when drawing the entity should you transform the units to pixels.